# Como saber o ultimo elemento em uma QListWidget?

Tags: c++, lista, qt

Eu tenho uma QListWidget chamada `list_toMerge` com alguns itens adicionados, então eu criei 2 botões para mudar a ordem dos itens. O botão up e o down. Primeiro olhe o código no botão up:

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_Mup_clicked()
{
    int currentRow = ui->list_toMerge->currentRow();
    qDebug() << currentRow;

    if(currentRow != 0){
        QString aux = ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow - 1)->text();

        ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow - 1)->setText(ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow)->text());
        ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow)->setText(aux);

        ui->list_toMerge->setCurrentRow(currentRow - 1);
    }

    ui->list_toMerge->update();
}
```

O if serve para não executar o código quando o item selecionado já for o item 0, que já está no topo pois já é o primeiro item. O problema é com o botão down:

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_Mdown_clicked()
{
    int currentRow = ui->list_toMerge->currentRow();

    qDebug() << currentRow;

    if(currentRow != ????????){
        QString aux = ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow + 1)->text();

        ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow + 1)->setText(ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow)->text());
        ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow)->setText(aux);

        ui->list_toMerge->setCurrentRow(currentRow + 1);
    }

    ui->list_toMerge->update();
}
```

Onde tem "????????" deveria estar a posição do ultimo item na lista (O ultimo a ser adicionado), mas eu não sei como obter esse valor. Como que eu faço pra obter a posição do ultimo item de uma QListWidget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema usando o método `count()` que retorna o numero de elementos na QListWidget. Assim eu mantenho o numero de elementos, e tendo o numero de elementos eu tenho o row do ultimo elemento. Com isso o Código corrigido ficou assim:

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_Mup_clicked()
{
    int currentRow = ui->list_toMerge->currentRow();

    if(currentRow > 0){
        QString aux = ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow - 1)->text();

        ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow - 1)->setText(ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow)->text());
        ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow)->setText(aux);

        ui->list_toMerge->setCurrentRow(currentRow - 1);
    }

    ui->list_toMerge->update();
}

void MainWindow::on_btn_Mdown_clicked()
{
    int currentRow = ui->list_toMerge->currentRow();

    if( (currentRow>=0) and (ui->list_toMerge->count()>0) and (ui->list_toMerge->count()!=(currentRow+1)) ){
        QString aux = ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow + 1)->text();

        ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow + 1)->setText(ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow)->text());
        ui->list_toMerge->item(currentRow)->setText(aux);

        ui->list_toMerge->setCurrentRow(currentRow + 1);
    }

    ui->list_toMerge->update();
}
```

Comment: Não seria mais fácil ler o count? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#count-prop

Comment: Porque ninguém me avisou que isso existia? Obrigado viu.
Se vc quiser faz uma resposta pra eu poder marcar como melhor.

Comment: Pode atualizar sua resposta mesmo... Fica a sugestão de ler o manual extensivamente (e não se esqueça de sempre olhar de quem as classes herdam. Tem muita coisa que está na "classe mãe" e não na que está usando.)